# freemarker how print variable if it not null and not print if it is null?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have this model

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
        String msisdn = request.getParameter("msisdn");
        modelAndView.addObject("msisdn", msisdn); //may be NULL
        return modelAndView;
```

and page where

```
<#if msisdn??>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="phone" value="${msisdn}">
 <#else>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="phone">
 </#if>
```

If msisdn == null I want show `placeholder="phone"` but if msisdn not null I want show it.

It is work but I think it is bad practic. I not want copy all string and dublicate it in code. Can I write like this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="phone" value="<#if msisdn != null>${msisdn}</#if>">
```

or

or  something else in freemarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `!` to do this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="phone" value="${msisdn!}">
```

Comment: @user5620472 it's true, you can check: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_depr_builtin.html

Comment: seems you can use`${msisdn?""}` to replace `!`

Comment: @ chengpohi - identifier excepted

Comment: Where does it say that it's deprecated? AFAIK it isn't. `?default` and `?if_exists` are deprecated, because there were superseded by `!`.

Comment: @ddekany Thanks call out. :)